# How do i use a ND filter without screwing it onto the lens?

Tags: filters, nd-filter

I want to use an ND filter so i can create long exposure pictures without over exposure but my camera had a UV filter on and i dropped it then the UV filter glass smashed and a part of the ring got jammed on so there is no way to get it off, and i have tried, lots. So i cannot attach another filter because the old one is jammed on. My question being can i even use an ND filter? I would be willing to hold it over the camera lens if that is what it takes. Thank you in advance.

P.S. I cannot take off my lens and put on another one because i use a bridge camera.

Comment: Note that if using a deep ND filter such as a big or small stopper (10 or 4 stops) it is important to seal between the lens and the filter to stop light leaking in. My best advice would be to see if there is a service company able to remove the old broken filter for you - otherwise you are going to have a lot of faffing around which you don't usually have time to do when working outside.

Comment: Take the camera to someone who can remove the broken ring.  It's not that hard when you have the right tools and the right knowledge.

Comment: @John Yes I have taken it to a photography shop and they said the best would be to just leave it in fear of damaging something.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but probably a more correct one.

You really should get the broken filter off the lens.  Sometimes filters get stuck and are hard to get off.  That is difficult to deal with because you don't want to damage anything in taking the filter off.

You have the advantage that the filter is already damaged, and filter damage to the filter doesn't matter.  You really should be able to get the old filter ring off the lens.

In a few rare cases when I had a filter that I just couldn't get off with any amount of reasonable finger pressure, I used a little bit of penetrating oil.  Oil and camera lenses don't mix well, so you have to use as little as possible and wipe the result extra carefully.  So far this has always worked.

If your filter ring got deformed, it will be even harder.  However, you have the advantage of being able to grip the ring with needle nose plyers and the like.  You don't care if the filter ring gets deformed in the process.  You just want to make sure that the lens doesn't get hurt.  You could (very carefully!) possibly even cut off a section of the old filter ring.

I just don't believe there isn't a way to take off the damaged filter, assuming the lens itself is still in good shape, as you say.

Comment: No sorry I did not put it in the question  but my filter has been deformed and I fear the tread has been bent beyond repair.

Answer (score 0):

take 2 squared thermocol sheets bigger than the diameter of lens, mark the lens outer size, cut to make a hole in square then take another piece mark inner lens size, cut, now sandwich the ND filter between two pieces and fix the whole model to lens toward the larger holed sheet.